# Using handlebarsjs as a template for Rails instead of HAML or Slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, handlebars.js, slim-lang

I'm potentially looking to standardize view/design templates for projects across the board with a singular template framework.  Given that we are starting to see work for JS frameworks that can leverage Handlebars, it would seem potentially prudent to likewise begin using Handlebars to replace our usage of HAML (via [Handlebars.rb](https://github.com/cowboyd/handlebars.rb) and [handlebars_assets](https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets)).

Does this, experientially, work effectively?  Or can you provide a link to some explanation of why or why not this will work or an example of such a use case?

Obviously HAML and (more sexy) Slim offer a cleaner template syntax for the most part, but Handlebars.js does have advantages that it carries from Liquid in that it's much more like plain HTML and therefore more "designer friendly."